# Is a hash table faster than document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have a node like this:

```
    <!-- lots of HTML here (including lots of nest unordered lists) -->
    <span id="spn123">Test</span>
    <!-- lots of html here -->
```

Burried under lots of levels of HTML and I also have a JavaScript hash table like this:

```
[
 /* lots of nodes here */
 { 123 : 'Test' }
 /* lots of nodes here */ 
]
```

Then would it be faster to use

```
document.getElementById('spn123').innerText;
```

or

```
data(123)
```

I would assume that both are handled by the browser natively and are very optimized, but would the latter be faster due to its flat structure and lack of additional DOM bloat?

Thanks!

Comment: Benchmark it. It will depend on the *specific* DOM and JS implementations. In the end it won't matter: if it does the algorithm itself should probably be reconsidered. (Both of these use-cases have been well-optimized. Also, JavaScript objects are *not* hash tables; they are maps. Implementations *may* choose to use hashing internally.)

Comment: The difference will be trivial unless you're talking about billions of operations. If you're talking about billions of operations, you're probably doing something weird.

Comment: All performance questions should be answered by running well designed tests that measure exactly what you care about in the browsers you care about them in.  Anything else is pure speculation.

Comment: *innerText* isn't supported by all browsers in use, so that will be interminably slow for some. ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm talking abouthundreds of thousands so I'll go with the last one which I prefer. RobG: Lol, recently I've been spoilt by jQuery and I just typed it straight in to SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be useful to know why you have both an object and a DOM representation. I assume hash is the single source of truth and the DOM renders the hash accordingly.

I would expect the hash lookup to be faster because the DOM can be slow, however this is mostly writing the DOM, not reading the DOM. I made a [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-hash-lookup/4) and the results vary drastically based on the browser.

In these scenarios, I like to make a function to abstract the implementation so it can be changed later without finding every reference to the lookup in the code:

```
function getItem(id) {
    return hash[id];
}
```

If you later find a more optimized way to lookup your data, you just change that function.

Update:
I changed the jsperf to use textContent but this will not work in older browsers.

Comment: That's what I thought - it will all be in the DOM eventually but I'd rather just use a flat hash map to look it up.

Comment: hashmap is slower on Chrome, has same speed on FF, but is faster on Safari ==>> no conclusion. http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-hash-lookup/2

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer to your question is, "It doesn't matter."

My thought is that as the commenters suggested, you might want to benchmark it somehow.

However, if I'm not mistaken, document.getElementById is the fastest method there is to select a single element on your page; it shouldn't be necessary to try to optimize it unless the number of operations you're performing is extreme.

Answer (score 0):

> but would the latter be faster due to its flat structure and lack of additional DOM bloat?

Unless one is significantly and noticeably slower than the other, use the one that makes the most sense. Objects are meant for data storage and retrieval (among other things), the DOM is meant to present it visually.

So use the Object for data storage and retrieval, use the DOM to display it in a meaningful way.